# Return Serializable object from FileStream?

Tags: asp.net, serialization, stream, filestream

I'm a little green when it comes to streaming and serialization...but what I want to do is make the Upload method on the server return a serializable object to the client (it is void right now).

I have a public class ServiceResult that I decorate with [Serializable], and a public class FileTransferService that implements IFileTransferService

```
[ServiceContract()]
public interface IFileTransferService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
    string Upload(FileTransferRequest request);
}
```

The implementation does its thing, and then at the end I create and serialize the object and try to return the string

```
return ServiceResultSerializer.SerializeAnObject(result);
```

On the client side I call this service using this class

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName = "IFileTransferService")]
public interface IFileTransferService
{

    // CODEGEN: Generating message contract since the wrapper name (FileTransferRequest) of message FileTransferRequest does not match the default value (Upload)
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(IsOneWay = false, Action = "http://tempuri.org/IFileTransferService/Upload")]
    string Upload(FileTransferRequest request);
}
```

I'm basically taking this project found on this blog: http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2007/08/29/sending-attachments-with-wcf.aspx

And trying to make it return a value that the client caller can use

I get an error right now that says:

> The operation 'Upload' could not be loaded because it has a parameter or return type of type System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message or a type that has MessageContractAttribute and other parameters of different types. When using System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message or types with MessageContractAttribute, the method must not use any other types of parameters.

Which i have no idea what it means :P I think because I'm trying to change the Service parameters.

Sorry if I'm being too general - any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think there's something missing from your posted code.  Where's your `ServiceResult` class you mentioned?  Also, what's the definition of `FileTransferRequest`?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like your `FileTransferRequest` class has `MessageContractAttribute` applied to it.

Since your input parameter has `MessageContractAttribute`, your response type should also have `MessageContractAttribute`, which `String` doesn't.  Try creating a `FileTransferResponse` class that has a single string-type property, and use that as your return type.